# passing value from python to php

Tags: php, python

I'm having a problem with a project. I need to do a detection system which uses python to communicate with electronic devices. I'm creating a detection system. The problem is that I want to detect and then send to a php file which serves as my user interface.

Python:

> if led is on, send on to php,
>
> if led is off, send off to php,

PHP:

> display [value receive from python]

Comment: How are these working together? A PHP application is *typically* very short lived and cannot really be "talked to" from a longer running process like Python. Perhaps you just want to *store* the value somewhere and *read* it from PHP when needed?

Comment: that might be true..maybe if i can save the value somewhere and retrieve it whenever i want that will be great..but i'm totally lost in php..can i do that with simple coding..?

Comment: Simple: a database. Maybe MySQL, maybe Redis, maybe just memcached, maybe just a plain file. All these things are easy to write to from Python and read from in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call php script directly:

php code:

```
 <?php
 $state = $argv[1];
 echo $state;
 ?>
```

python code:

```
from subprocess import *
#ledstate='on'
p = Popen(['/usr/bin/php','<php file name>',ledstate],stdout=PIPE)
print p.stdout.read()
```

If you want to call via server:

php code:

```
<?php
$state = $_GET["led"];
echo $state;
?>
```

python code:

```
import urllib2
#ledstate='on'
req = urllib2.Request(url='http://example.com/<php file name>?led=%s' % ledstate )
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print f.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), to call the php command passing the variable from python:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["list","of","php" ,"commands","off/on"])
```

If you want to store the output use `check_output`

Answer (score 0):

now i already got a way to retrieve data form python using php..

```
<?php
$result = exec("sudo python /home/pi/detect_led.py");
$resultData = json_decode($result);

print $resultData;
?>
```

but the problem is..the data is slow..i mean..when there's changes i have to refresh 2 time for it to change its value..so is there any where i can change to make it correct..?