# get variable from python script into php page

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi2

my Python script returns:

```
python /home/pi/sht/sht31.py
False
True
False
Temperature: 8.10668945312
Humidity: 83.49609375
```

I need to print humidity and Temperature into an index.php

I tried:

```
exec('sudo python /home/pi/sht/sht31.py' , $output);
var_dump($output);
```

but output is:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "False" [1]=> string(4) "True" [2]=> string(5) "False" [3]=>       string(26) "Temperature: 8.07464599609" [4]=> string(23) "Humidity: 83.5327148438" }
```

it is possible to extract only temperature and humidity ?

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780729/passing-value-from-python-to-php)

Comment: can you modify the python script? If yes, then I suggest to change it to write out its output in json format.
If not, then you have multiple choices.

If you know, that temperature is always in the 5th line, split the poutput by '\n', take the fifth entry, explode it by white space and take the second entry

Comment: Modifiy the python script to not print the True/False values

Comment: I removed true and false but print is similar :  array(2) { [0]=> string(25) "Temperature: 8.4912109375" [1]=> string(23) "Humidity: 81.3537597656" }

Comment: You have an array with Temperature and Humidity, isn't that what you need? `echo $output[3];` for Temperature and `echo $output[4];` for Humidity

Comment: echo $output[4]; already tried and return nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can add this into your code and when you run it add the two files for example: python ex0.py ex0.txt ex1.txt                              I hope this helps if it doesn't sorry have a great day

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv 
print ("Copying from %s to %s.") % (from_file, to_file)

in_file=open(from_file)
indata= in_file.read()
```