# How to pass a variable from Python 3.x to PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x

I have a small Python 3.x script with a variable:

```
a = 10
```

and want to pass the variable to a PHP script in the same folder. What code is needed to use that variable in PHP?

Comment: Pass it as a command line argument when running the PHP script, then use `$argv` in the PHP script to access it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing value from python to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780729/passing-value-from-python-to-php)

Comment: No, absolutely not. I tried that before and the only answer I understand there uses urllib2 and that's not part of Python 3.x as far as I understand.

Comment: Does this work?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command